# Wagtail how to filter pages a user has view access to via their groups

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-search

I am implementing a search function that returns pages the user has access to via their groups. Pages have these settings set via the Wagtail admin page privacy settings when editing.

For example, a page could only be visible to users in the Editors group. So when a user NOT in the Editors group searches for this page it should be filtered out.

How would one efficiently filter pages not accessible by the user this way? I could not find any clear way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question for search engine optimization purposes.

After studying the Wagtail source code I discovered Wagtail uses a `PageViewRestriction` model internally.

I ended up using this snippet to solve my issue:

```py
from wagtail.core.models import Page, PageViewRestriction

def filter_pages(user):
    pages = Page.objects.live()

    # Unauthenticated users can only see public pages
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        pages = pages.public()
    # Superusers can implicitly view all pages. No further filtering required
    elif not user.is_superuser:
        # Get all page ids where the user's groups do NOT have access to
        disallowed_ids = PageViewRestriction.objects.exclude(groups__id=user.groups.all()).values_list("page", flat=True)
        # Exclude all pages with disallowed ids
        pages = pages.exclude(id__in=disallowed_ids)

    return pages
```